# Return part of groovy collections

Tags: groovy, collections

I'm new at groovy and programming language's, and I'm trying to return as a string just a "Second Admin" matching date with "End Transition" record at log's are called toString=Second Admin and Second Admin=End Transition. I know I need to do it somehow using first for each for scan Collection then if and return value what I need but didn't know how to code it

Thanks in Advice for all help and hint

```
   def NameOfPerson= changeHistories.collect {history ->;
       history.getChangeItemBeans().findResults {ChangeItemBean change ->;
        log.info("###############################################$change");
       }
}
```

Output :

```
[fieldType=jira,field=Workflow,from=10306,fromString=Software Simplified Workflow for Project TP,to=10329,toString=Software Simplified Workflow for Project DEMO,created=2017-06-16 21:54:20.183]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10000,fromString=To Do,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-25 17:20:25.989]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-25 17:21:23.134]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-25 17:21:25.613]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-25 17:52:01.677]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-25 17:52:06.668]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-25 19:08:25.628]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-25 19:08:28.563]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-25 19:18:30.001]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-25 19:18:33.045]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=admin,fromString=Second Admin,to=ID10101,toString=Main Admin,created=2017-06-26 04:55:11.57]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-26 04:55:20.84]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=ID10101,fromString=Main Admin,to=admin,toString=Second Admin,created=2017-06-26 04:55:20.84]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-26 04:55:24.836]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=admin,fromString=Second Admin,to=ID10101,toString=Main Admin,created=2017-06-26 04:59:59.658]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-26 05:00:03.354]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=ID10101,fromString=Main Admin,to=admin,toString=Second Admin,created=2017-06-26 05:00:03.354]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-26 05:00:06.645]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=admin,fromString=Second Admin,to=ID10101,toString=Main Admin,created=2017-06-26 05:05:45.697]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-26 05:05:48.899]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=ID10101,fromString=Main Admin,to=admin,toString=Second Admin,created=2017-06-26 05:05:48.899]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10216,fromString=Start Transition,to=10300,toString=End Transition,created=2017-06-26 05:05:51.99]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=admin,fromString=Second Admin,to=ID10101,toString=Main Admin,created=2017-06-26 05:07:13.985]
    [fieldType=jira,field=status,from=10300,fromString=End Transition,to=10216,toString=Start Transition,created=2017-06-26 05:07:16.563]
    [fieldType=jira,field=assignee,from=ID10101,fromString=Main Admin,to=admin,toString=Second Admin,created=2017-06-26 05:07:16.563]
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: Output provided, regards input I'm cant do that code return information from jira  so I'm not able to return a input info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as soon as you can't provide input/output data samples, here is the generic answer:

to find one item in list you can use `find` method and to find list of items (sublist) use `findAll` method

both defined in groovy collection: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

just a sample:

```
def list = [
    [a:1,b:'bbb01',c:'ccc01'],
    [a:2,b:'bbb02',c:'ccc02'],
    [a:3,b:'bbb01',c:'ccc03'],
    [a:4,b:'bbb02',c:'ccc04'],
]

println list.find{it.a==3}
//prints> [a:3, b:bbb01, c:ccc03]

println list.find{it.a==3}.c
//prints> ccc03

println list.find{it.a==0}?.c
//prints> null
//without ? throws NullPointerException

//findAll builds a sub-list for which expression is true
println list.findAll{it.b=='bbb02'}
//prints> [[a:2, b:bbb02, c:ccc02], [a:4, b:bbb02, c:ccc04]]

//collect builds tha list of the same size but with transformed values
println list.collect{it.b}
//prints> [bbb01, bbb02, bbb01, bbb02]
```